# google captcha from jquery to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this snippet to validate my Google Captcha form. This is done in Jquery though and would like to change it to vanilla Javascript. I found some resources online but just can't get it right, here is one of them: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/

Here is my working snippet in Jquery, how would I change it to Vanilla Javascript?

```
$('.contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
  e.preventDefault();
  $( '.msg-error').text( "Tick to confirm you are human" )}});
```

Comment: why was this down voted?

Comment: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/#working-with-events this is the relevant section - your jQuery is using the `submit` event, so you'll want to use that with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. Thank you for the reference @user7290583.

```
document.querySelector('.contact-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
  e.preventDefault();
  errorMsg = document.getElementById("msg-error");
  errorMsg.textContent = "Please tick box to confirm you are not a robot";
}});
```